# input type="number" contains null rather than character

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, typescript

I have a `number` input field which I want to validate with Angular2:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="foo" id="foo"
       [min]="0" [max]="42" [(ngModel)]="foo" formControlName="foo">
```

So far this works fine in Chrome, because Chrome ignores chars as input (doesn't insert them into the input -> input is empty -> required validation triggers, or there is already a number so the min/max validation triggers).

#### Problem

Firefox on the other hand lets the user input chars into the input and here is the problem, if I insert chars, then the required validation triggers and the value of the form control evaluates as `null` which results in this:

[image: required validation triggers, but input is not empty]

#### Question

I want to distinguish between empty values and invalid patterns but the only way I found to achieve this is by making the `input type="text"` and using a pattern validator, because the value of the input is `null` (if it contains chars) and the pattern validator does not trigger on the `input type="number"`.

- Is there a way to access the actual value of the field using the Angular2 `FormGroup` object (even `document.querySelector('#foo').value` evaluates to `null` although the input contains `42bar`)?
- Or is there a way to check if the input field contains chars?
- Or is there no other way than using `input type="text"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you type something into a "number" input that's not a number, the value will be `null`. That's the way it's supposed to work.

You can check the `.validity.valid` flag to see whether the field has a valid value in it; an empty value is considered valid for number fields.

Comment: If I check the `FormGroup` for my foo input field it only has a `valid` attribute which also evaluates to `false` if the input is empty - due to the required validator (if I don't use the required validator how would I check whether the input is not empty and does not contain chars?)

Comment: I don't understand; why not check the `<input>` element itself? That said, in my opinion HTML5 form validation is not very useful, or maybe "flexible" is a better word. Personally I only drop "number" elements onto a page when I know I'm rendering on a touch-screen device.

Comment: The problem is that I have a `FormGroup` so I have no way of directly accessing the `<input>` element, if I want to select the element I have to do something like `document.querySelector('#foo')` but that means I have to map the name of my `FormGroup` element to the id in the DOM which is awkward and defeats the purpose of separating model and template ...

Comment: You could also select for "input[type=number]" or something like that.