# Getting current input value in angular template driven form validator

Tags: angular, forms, angular-custom-validators

I have a question regarding an input element type number that I want to validate in a template-driven form:

As the first goal, it should accept only positive integer values. For this, I have created a validator function that gets the input value, evaluates a regex expression, and returns errors if it fails. I wrapped it within a directive and used it with the input element in the template. So far, all is good and it works perfectly.

As the second goal, it should accept a `NULL` value. For example, since the field is not mandatory, the end user could leave it empty (`NULL`) and then submit the form. At first, I thought that extending the validator with a condition for when the element is `NULL` will do the job, and it did. But the problem comes when typing values like -2 or 2.3 or 2.3-... in those cases the validator gets also the input value `NULL` so I cannot distinguish when the user leaves the input field empty (`NULL`) or when he's typing an invalid value. I guess the `NULL` comes from a previous built-in validator running. Is there a way to get access to the actual value of the input field?

this is how the code pretty much looks in the template:

```
<input
 name="testInputField"
 id="xyz"
 type="number"
 step="1"
 min="0"
 [(ngModel)]="controllerVariable"
 myDirective/>
```

...and this is how the directive looks like

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, Validator, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
    
export function myValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  const regExp = /^\d+$/;

  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    return control.value === null
      ? null
      : regExp.test(control.value)
        ? null
        : { myValidator: { valid: false } };
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: MyDirective,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class MyDirective implements Validator {
  public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return myValidator()(control);
  }
};
```

Any hints or ideas to refactor my solution are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the question, I learnt something new today! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756020/input-type-number-contains-null-rather-than-character
This seems like a really dumb side effect of applying `type="number"` to an <input> field, I'm actually shocked this is the way it works. One option is clearly to not use `type="number"` and instead use `type="text"`. Assuming this is not a valid option, I would consider passing in the value from the <input> DOM element itself, e.g. using @ViewChild() and `viewChildVariable.nativeElement.target.value`.

Comment: @nate-kumar even with your approach, value is `NULL` in the `nativeElement`. After having a look at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) I come to the conclusion that if I want to accept `NULL` as a valid value, `<input>` type "number" won't work. I believe choosing the type "text" will do the job